# How to run the symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner in symfony framework and I want to run my function Which I

Created in BlogController

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog")
     */
    public function showAction()
    {
      echo "hello friend";
    }
}
?>


C:\xampp\htdocs\mysymfony\src\AppBundle\Controller
```

mysymfony is project name.

Here is my routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

When I hit URL:-

**http://localhost/mysymfony/blog**

I get this Error

**

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
```

**

I don't know how structure of URL to run BLOG function.Please resolved this problem

Comment: Please post the complete error you get? It must be very long in `dev` environment.

Comment: @Alok I changed the question means show the full  error

Comment: It's not a Symfony specific error. This might be because you've not configured the Symfony project correctly.

Comment: @Alok Please tell me how to configure the symfony

Comment: It looks more like an apache error. Have you [setup apache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) correctly?

Comment: You can find it on Symfony's documentation.

Comment: @xtreamwayz yes, I run another project which is created in the codeigniter. That working properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you run your url in the root directory.

With your Controller you'll need to run `http://localhost/mysymfony/web/app_dev.php/blog` for the development environment or `http://localhost/mysymfony/web/app.php/blog` for the production environment.

Or configure your Apache to run directly to `web/`. You can find that guide [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html).